# Is it possible to displace a mesh based on Light Path node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, displacement

At the image below I expected the cube to be displaced by plus 1 unit in x,y,z axis. However it is staying as it is (notice the yellow outline).[image]

Comment: Try plug Invert node between Light Pass and Vector Displacement.

Comment: From the light path node. Only 0 is outputted. So invert just converts that to 1. So it doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.